# Get repeating element in XSLT 2.0 with few element transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have gone through quite few threads about repeating elements and how to use xsl identity template. But my requirement is to repeat most of the elements with couple of fields requiring transformation.

Here is my input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Roots xmlns="urn:com.mydish/extps">
    <Root>
        <Worker>100</Worker>
        <Group></Group>
        <Amount>1165851.81</Amount>
        <Currency>USD</Currency>
        <Check>201705091204</Check>
        <File_Name>1.pdf</File_Name>
    </Root>
     <Root>
        <Worker>20</Worker>
        <Group></Group>
        <Amount>231456.41</Amount>
        <Currency>USD</Currency>
        <Check>201705091204</Check>
        <File_Name>2.pdf</File_Name>
    </Root>
 </Roots>
```

Output has to be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Roots xmlns="urn:com.mydish/extps">
    <Root>
        <Worker>C10</Worker>
        <Group>Group1</Group>
        <Amount>1165851.81</Amount>
        <Currency>USD</Currency>
        <Check>201705091204</Check>
        <File_Name>1.pdf</File_Name>
    </Root>
     <Root>
        <Worker>C20</Worker>
        <Group>Group2</Group>
        <Amount>231456.41</Amount>
        <Currency>USD</Currency>
        <Check>201705091204</Check>
        <File_Name>2.pdf</File_Name>
    </Root>
 </Roots>
```

So, logic is depending on input Worker's length, output Worker and Group fields to be transformed.

If input Worker's length is 3 digits, then output Worker will be C and first two digits (C10) and Group will be Group1. If input worker length is 2 digits, then then concatenate just C to output Worker like (C20) and Group will be Group2.

Rest has to be same as in input.

How to transform this?
Is the below one right? I understand this will not work as-is.

```
<Worker>
    <xsl:value-of select="if string-length(Worker)='3' then concat('C',substring(Worker,1,2)) else concat('C',Worker)" />
</Worker>
<Group>
     <xsl:value-of select="if string-length(Worker)='3' then 'Group1' else 'Group2'" />
</Group>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:my="urn:com.mydish/extps"
  xpath-default-namespace="urn:com.mydish/extps">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="Worker">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="if (string-length() = 3)
        then concat('C', substring(., 1, 2))
        else concat('C', .)" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Group">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="if (string-length(../Worker) = 3)
        then 'Group1' else 'Group2'" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

You were quite close to the right solution.

I added namespace handling and made slight changes to your code.

Maybe you should read a little to learn:

- about namespace handling,
- setting of a *default namespace* for *XPath* expressions,
- the notion of a *current object* (`.`) inside a template and
  what is its value,
- how to refer to a sibling object (e.g. *Worker* element
  from within *Group* template.

Comment: Thank you, this is working. Sure, will learn the topics which you pointed it out. It really helps.

Answer (score 0):

For the `Worker`, you could do simply:

```
<xsl:template match="Worker">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:text>C</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 1, 2)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

For the `Group`, you just need a few syntax corrections:

```
<xsl:template match="Group">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="if (string-length(../Worker)=3) then 'Group1' else 'Group2'" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This is in addition to the *identity transform* template, of course.

Comment: Alternatively, use two templates for Group: `<xsl:template match="Group[matches(../Worker, '...')]"><Group>Group1</Group></xsl:template>`